# Binding items dynamically to TreeTable component

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to bind items to TreeTable (sap.ui.table.treetable) component on button press. I have made odata service with entitysets and navigation, but after button click TreeTable is still empty (no error occurred).

My view:

```
<TreeTable
    id="itemsTable"
    selectionMode="Single"
    visibleRowCountMode="Auto"      
    selectionBehavior="RowSelector"
    enableColumnReordering="true">      
    <columns>
        <Column label="Item" template="text"/>
    </columns>  

</TreeTable>
```

Controller code:

```
onButtonPress: function() {
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("itemsTable");         
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();     

    oTable.setModel(oModel);

    oTable.bindRows({
        path: "/itemSet",               
        templateShareable: true,
        parameters: {
            navigation: "subitemSet"
        }
    });         
}
```

How to bind data to TreeTable correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When youy check the binding on the control with UI5 inspector, does it have the data your are looking for?

And [sap.ui.table.Column](https://ui5.sap.com/1.67.0/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column) doesn't seem to have the template property, try the following code:

```
<columns>
    <Column label="Item">
        <template>
            <m:Text text="{ItemDescription}" wrapping="false" />
        </template>
    <Column/>
</columns>
```

Comment: I tried your code but without effect. Yes, in UI5 inspector my data is there.